# Opening a file using Sandbox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox

OK, so I know that under the new **SandBox** guidelines, opening a file must abide by certain rules (a.k.a. the opening action must be triggered by the user using an `NSOpenPanel`, given of course the necessary "open" permissions).

**However, here's the catch :**

- In my application, I've got an `NSOutlineView` with a complete file manager in it (the full tree structure)
- The user is supposed to be able to select a file from the outline view and then the app will open it.

How am I supposed to do that, given that the app should be 100% sandbox-compliant? Is there any known workaround? Is it even possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do that. In order to show the contents of a folder within your app's UI, you'd first have to get the user to open it either using an open panel or dragging it in from the Finder.

Comment: Oh, great... I really love Sandbox... :S

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, as @omz said, your application needs to request permission to access the folder containing all the files/folders that your application is showing. You don't need permission of individual files, but can get an entire directory structure as a single permission, and then store that as a security scoped bookmark so future executions of your application will already have that permission.

You could even at app launch ask the user for permission to access the entire hard drive, or their entire user directory.

You can use this class I wrote to wrap all that up into a single function call, which will then persist the permission so they are only asked on first run. https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess

Alternatively if you want to do it with NSOpenPanel manually, just take a look at the code in [AppSandboxFileAccess](https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess) as it uses it to get permissions and then persist those permissions.